# How do I deal with OpenStreetMap Overpass API XML containing references to non-present nodes?

Tags: xml, mapping, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm using the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to query a bounding box:

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=node(44.8108,-0.638973,44.9167,44.8108);out;way(44.8108,-0.638973,44.9167,44.8108);out;
```

which is supposed to return all nodes and routes in the region (44.8108,-0.638973,44.9167,44.8108).

The XML parsing shows that some ways are composed of nodes that are not defined in the XML. For example, `way[id=459837502]` is composed of `node[ref=4557387912]`, but there is no information (longitude, latitude, ...) about that node in the file.

What kind of query can I use to get a complete map (in terms of data coherence)?

---

EDIT. even worse: I've got a route (n1, ...., n100) where n1 and n100 are defined in the nodes section but none of the intermediate nodes.

EDIT2. the map size is 150Mbytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get ways in a bounding box with all of their respective nodes, you need to use a different syntax:

`( way(44.8108,-0.638973,44.9167,44.8108); >; );out;`